# yq fails with "permission denied"

Tags: visual-studio-code, yq

Why does this fail in the terminal of vscode?

```
cat foo.json | yq -P  > foo.yaml
```

> Error: write /dev/stdout: permission denied

But this does work:

```
cat foo.json | yq -P | cat > foo.yaml
```

I can create the file "foo.yaml" with `touch` and remove it with `rm`.

I don't think it is related to file/directory permissions.

I think it must be something special about the tool `yq`.

No `sudo` is involved.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

This only happens in the console of vscode, it works in a gnome-terminal.

`yq` is installed via snap.

It could be related to this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1849753

Comment: Do you run this as your current user, or with `sudo`? Sound like an permission issue and not related to yq. (unable to reproduce here on debian11)

Comment: @0stone0 today I tried it again. It fails only in the console of vscode, it works in a gnome-terminal.

Comment: a work around I found is the following: yq -P '.' your_file.json -oy | grep '' > your_file.yaml

Comment: Got the same error

Answer (score 4):

Not a solution of the root cause, but at least an explanation and a work around:

This is related to vscode, not to yq.

The same happens with other commands. For example: kubectl:

```
kubectl run --image=nginx nginx --dry-run=client -o yaml  > p.yaml

error: write /dev/stdout: permission denied
```

I never understood why snap was created. It seems to be related to this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1849753

I installed kubectl (and yq) via [brew for linux](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux) and now I don't get the "permission denied" error.

Comment: Sure enough, trying the same command in a regular terminal worked. Thank you!